# Calculate difference between rows with counter values in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I got table T1 where I update some counters values

```
id, unix_time_stamp, counter1, counter10
1 , 1333435800     , 55      , 80
```

then i got table T2 where i copy those values

```
id, unix_time_stamp, counter1, counter10, value1, value10
1 , 1333435800     , 55      , 80       , 0     , 0
2 , 1333435801     , 60      , 87       , 5     , 7
3 , 1333435802     , 70      , 90       , 10    , 3
3 , 1333435804     , 80      , 100      , 5     , 5
```

this is done with some trigger function

```
INSERT INTO T2 (unix_time_stamp, counter1, counter10) SELECT unix_time_stamp, counter1, counter10 FROM T1 WHERE id=1
```

What i want is to calculate value1, value10 as a

```
(current_counter1 - last_counter1)/(current_time - last_time)
```

and put them in this insert.

for example value 1 with timestamp 1333435804 will be

```
value1=(80-70)/(1333435804-1333435802) = 5
```

other words

```
insert into t2
(unix_time_stamp, counter1, counter10, value1)
SELECT unix_time_stamp, counter1, counter10, 
(counter1 - (select counter1 from T1 order by unix_time_stamp DESC LIMIT 1)/
(unix_time_stamp - (select unix_time_stamp from T1 order by unix_time_stamp DESC LIMIT 1)
FROM T1 WHERE id=1
```

but i want this in a little shorter version because i got 10 counters :)

Whole situation is little bit complicated, and i got some reason to not do this outside SQL

I am using sqlite

This is just to complicated to me :)
Please help.

Comment: your question is unclear please tell more clearly what you really want

Comment: updated, hope it is more clear right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the following query calculates all data you need for your insert clause:

```
SELECT 1e0 * (cur.counter1 - prv.counter1)/(cur.unix_time_stamp - prv.unix_time_stamp)   AS [value1]
, 1e0 * (cur.counter10 - prv.counter10)/(cur.unix_time_stamp - prv.unix_time_stamp)      AS [value10]
, cur.counter1 AS [cur_counter1], cur.counter10 AS [cur_counter10], cur.unix_time_stamp AS [cur_time]
, prv.counter1 AS [prv_counter1], prv.counter10 AS [prv_counter10], prv.unix_time_stamp AS [prv_time]
FROM T1 cur, T1 prv
WHERE cur.counter1 = (SELECT MAX(aux_0.counter1) FROM T1 aux_0)
AND prv.counter1 = (SELECT MAX(aux_1.counter1) FROM T1 aux_1 WHERE aux_1.counter1 < cur.counter1);
```

Comment: hmm what does SELECT 1e0 mean ? and what is aux_0 ? ..i just don't follow, this is too complicated for me .

Comment: Since counter fields are integers, the resulting expression would be rounded to `INT`; the `1e0 * (exp)` is used to typecast the resulting expression to float (I guess you could use `1.0 * (exp)` as well).

Comment: `aux_0` is a simple alias for table T1 when used in the subquery to get the `max(counter1)`. Albeit it is not mandatory in this case, I like to always alias tables and explicit identify from which table the fields come from.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear. Is this anywhere close?

```
DECLARE @Id int = 1

DECLARE @LastCounter1 int,
        @LastCounter10 int,
        @LastTime timestamp,

SELECT TOP 1    @LastCounter1 = counter1,
                @LastCounter10 = counter10,
                @LastTime = unix_time_stamp
FROM            T2
WHERE           id = @Id
ORDER BY        unix_time_stamp DESC

INSERT INTO T2 (id, unix_time_stamp, counter1, counter10, value1, value10)
SELECT      unix_time_stamp,
            counter1,
            counter10,
            ((counter1 - @LastCounter1) / (unix_time_stamp - @LastTime)),
            ((counter10 - @LastCounter10) / (unix_time_stamp - @LastTime))
```

Updated answer:

```
INSERT INTO T2 (id, unix_time_stamp, counter1, counter10, value1, value10)
SELECT      T1.id,
            T1.unix_time_stamp,
            T1.counter1,
            T1.counter10,
            ((T1.counter1 - [Last].counter1) / (T1.unix_time_stamp - [Last].unix_time_stamp)), 
            ((T1.counter10 - [Last].counter10) / (T1.unix_time_stamp - [Last].unix_time_stamp))
FROM        T1
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT TOP 1    id,
                                counter1,
                                counter10,
                                unix_time_stamp
                FROM            T2
                WHERE           id = 1
                ORDER BY        unix_time_stamp DESC
            ) [Last] ON T1.id = [Last].id
WHERE       T1.id = 1
```

Comment: Yes it is "close", thank you, but i just edited my post to be more clear. I am using sqlite but this look like t-sql hope i find a way to translate this :)